# SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: Geometry has Z dimension but column does not when updating SRID of PolygonZ column in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, polygon, srid, z-value

I am trying to update the SRID of a PolygonZ column using:

```sql
select UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'bfp_clusters', 'convex_hull', 4326) ;
```

I get the following error:

```
SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: Geometry has Z dimension but column does not
  Where: SQL statement "ALTER TABLE public.bfp_clusters ALTER COLUMN convex_hull TYPE  geometry(Geometry, 4326) USING public.ST_SetSRID(convex_hull,4326);"
PL/pgSQL function updategeometrysrid(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying,integer) line 80 at EXECUTE
SQL statement "SELECT public.UpdateGeometrySRID('',$1,$2,$3,$4)"
PL/pgSQL function updategeometrysrid(character varying,character varying,character varying,integer) line 5 at SQL statement
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.bfp_clusters
ALTER COLUMN convex_hull TYPE geometry(GeometryZ, 32643)
USING ST_Force3D(convex_hull);
```

followed by:

```sql
select UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'bfp_clusters', 'convex_hull', 4326) ;
```

does the trick!

Comment: Instead of "select UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'bfp_clusters', 'convex_hull', 4326) ;
"--- could I have used: UPDATE public.bfp_clusters
SET convex_hull = ST_SetSRID(convex_hull, 4326);   ?

Comment: `UpdateGeometrySRID` will modify the table AND will set the SRID of each geometry, while the `update` will only set the SRID of each geometry. Since you have used a different SRID in your `alter` statement and in the `update` statement, the last command will error out while the 1st would work (and wreck the data by setting a different SRID without reprojecting the geometries)